# Is Exchange 2010 still supported for multi-forest hybrid Exchange deployment?

Tags: exchange

We have the following environment:

Company A
Forest companya.com
Exchange 2010 SP3 (SMTP domain companya.com)

Company B
Forest companyx.com
Exchange 2010 SP3 (SMTP domain companyb.com)

I am thinking of using multi-forest hybrid migration to 1x O365 tenant.

However, I saw somewhere on the Internet that Exchange 2010 does not seem to be supported in this scenario.

Can someone please confirm this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-150/jj873754(v=exchg.150)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: https://practical365.com/blog/exchange-multi-forest-hybrid-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Saying `"I saw somewhere on the Internet that Exchange 2010 does not seem to be supported in this scenario."` without linking to what you read really isn't helpful to us. Where did you read that?

Comment: Here is the link:
http://msexchangeguru.com/2016/10/20/e2010-supported-for-multi-forest-hybrid/

Comment: The article states that it is supported. It's a bit misleading because the author states that it isn't supported, but then corrects himself and says that it is supported.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty.  I am relieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange 2010 is supported until October 13, 2020.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-2010-end-of-support-is-coming/ba-p/607810

You can also use FastTrack migration service for free if you have 150 or more licenses purchased. They will help you plan and execute your migration to Exchange Online.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/fasttrack/o365-fasttrack-benefit-for-office-365

Comment: Thanks Jevgenij for the great information!

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t hear this limit. Multiple forests, each with their own hybrid connection into a single Office 365 tenant, is supported from Exchange 2010 to 2019.

You could refer to the following thread:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/72fde8d5-ef55-48c9-acd0-0f344f49d533/multi-forest-exchange-hybrid-with-single-o365-tenant?forum=onlineservicesexchange